# How to add Filter picker in column header of Ext JS Grid 3.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, extjs3

I want to add filter picker (that has options for filter data of column) in the column header of a grid. I'm using Ext JS 3.2.2

I am getting this:

[image: Existing image]

I want my header like this:

[image: With Filter]

How to add filter plugin in my grid?

Also I am trying this in code but not getting filter in drop down.

```
this.filters = new Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilter({
            filters:this.filter
        }) ; 
        grid.plugins = [this.filters],
        grid.features = [{
                ftype : this.filters
            }
        ];
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use filder in header of `grid` you need to write by following manner. 
diclear array of filter and then give scope to grid. Then write

```
grid.filters = new Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters({
            filters:this.filter
        }) ;
```

Write Plugin

```
grid.plugins = [this.filters];
```

Where you adding column write

```
grid.filter{
    type: 'list',
    dataIndex: "DATAINDEX",
    local : local,
    dataForFilter : data
};
```

Data will come from the store. You cam modify as per you requirement. This is just basic what I will suggest you to achieve.